# How to grep/search ALL the data pulled by a web page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've been using Chrome's Developer tools and it's easy (using the Network tab) to see all the data that is being pulled to build the web page that's being loaded, including the initial source data.

But how do I search/grep thru all the subsequent documents being pulled including XHR calls?

Thanks in advance!